Reusable agent {} block in Jenkins declarative pipeline?
I have a fairly long agent {} block which includes a complex docker block, customWorkspace, etc.
This agent block is used in a number of parallel stages (for Linux builds) but not on all pipeline stages.
Is there any way I can re-use (DRY) this agent block?
Some of the things I've tried are:

Assigning the block to a global variable using def
Returning the block from a function
Returning the block from a shared library function (vars/myFunction.groovy), implementing call() in that file

In all those attempts I get errors such as:
Only "agent none", "agent any" or "agent {...}" are allowed.
No agent type specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, label, none]
